# how to index dynamic created profile pages urls

Tags: seo, search-engine, google-search, bing

I have large amount of dynamically generated public profile pages for different companies so i want to index them on google for seo without using sitemap.xml. I have created the link for the public profile page of each company in there account page which opens only after login. Will google be able to index the url from the link i created in there account page? I want some thing like facebook or linked in indexing work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Google won't be able to crawl that if you need to be logged in to get to the page.

Pages on Facebook, for example, have privacy settings set by their users. If the profile is public, Google is able to crawl it. Google follows links to the page, so it's able to find it. When something is shared on other people's profiles, or on other websites, Google follows these links and finds the content.

Comment: ok thanks, does google index the urls generated by jquery and javascript? And can you suggest me proper way to get all the public profile pages to google?

Comment: Google claims that they understand JavaScript well, but I would always make content avaible in HTML first and then enhance it using JS.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement

If you want your pages indexed by Google, make them in plain HTML, enhace using JS and make them easy to crawl - they should be linked properly from your website, so bots can follow these links and find your pages.